# Problem installing and uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: installation, firefox, uninstall

I bought a new PC and as I have windows on my laptop I thought I would give Ubuntu a try.

I downloaded the ISO, burned the Disk Image and installed it, but I get nothing to work properly.

As a result, I decided to uninstall it, but it seems that I cant do that neither:

- Firefox gives error messages
- Wi-Fi drops every few minutes, it is hopeless
- The mags make it look like a better type of windows but it is beyond me.

Can any one help me either get it to work or remove it?

I am 65 if you can guide me slowly I will try.

Comment: Have you tried updating? That fixes a lot of issues. Also, could you be more specific as to what your problem is? For instance, what are the error messages Firefox is giving you?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! It would really help if you mentioned the Ubuntu version you installed and analyze your problems in more depth.

Comment: Also, you should tell us your computer specs. Because it could be probably that your computer doesn't have the minimums required hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A recovery disc is what you need. If you don't have it, request one from your manufacturer.

For now,

type this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, you may get close with Ubuntu in the mean time, until you are able to recover your laptop's factory state.

Answer (score 0):

May be you wi-fi needs special drivers? Go to System settings->Software and updates -> Additional drivers and see if it suggests something. 
Also, sometimes Ubuntu installs damaged, but works fine after reinstallation. Why this happens is a mystery for common people.